# Show latest images first after being taken from directory

Tags: php, html, image

I'm currently working on a project where you can upload an image to a directory and then displaying them on the site. But, the latest image being uploaded is at the bottom and the oldest at the top. Can I reverse this in anyway? Tell me if I am totally on the wrong track. I'm new to php but here is a snippet of where the image from the directory being uploaded:

```
//upload from folder

$files = glob("images/*.*");
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
$image = $files[$i];
echo '<img src="'.$image.'"><br>';
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do they appear in the directory?

Comment: They appear alphabetically. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$files = glob("images/*.*");
$files = array_reverse($files);
```

Comment: Yeah, I had to wait like 3 min. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

sorry i can't comment. just wanted to ask that when you are uploading the images, are you saving there details somewhere in the database, if yes, you can save the filename and time of upload in the database and can use the same to retrieve the images with latest time

Comment: I'm currently not using a database to store the details in, is it a recommendation or can I accomplish this in another way? Thanks

Comment: i won't recommend doing it without database as it gives you more control over the files. But you can use [link]http://in1.php.net/filemtime[/link] filemtime() function to short the files, or may be during uploading your files you can save them with some number eg. 1,2,3,4, etc and then can call the in decreasing order, but for doing the same you need to save the last used number in some file or database so that you can work using that number.